# Adding a legend to Matplotlib based on string in column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to add a legend to this for loop. I'm having trouble as the colours are based on whether a column contains a string. Please see my dataframe below.

```
df: 
          Action   x1    y1
          goal     10     40
          miss     35     33
          goal     16     27
```

I want to include a legend that has a red dot for when df.Action contains goal, and blue for all other actions. Please see my current for loop below.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
        color="red" if "goal" in df.iloc[i].Action else "blue"

        plt.plot(int(df["x1"].iloc[i]), int(df["y1"].iloc[i]),"o", color = color)

    plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the legend handles you get a lot of flexibility and control.

e.g.

```
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
legendBlobs = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='red', label='Goooooal'),
               Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='blue', label='Not a Gooooooal')]

plt.legend(handles=legendBlobs)
```

[image]

or

```
legendBlobs = [Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='red', label='Goooooal', markersize=10, linestyle=""),
               Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='blue', label='Not a Gooooooal', markersize=10, linestyle="")]

plt.legend(handles=legendBlobs)
```

[image]